# Glimpse Null Reference Error PostImplementation

Tags: glimpse

When I enable glimpse and whenever I navigate to a page with any parameters in my MVC 3 site I get this error: -

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Glimpse.Mvc.AlternateType.GetBinder.PostImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context, TimerResult timerResult) +146
   Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context) +73
   Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) +165

Anyone know how I can fix this?

It seems any url with a parameter causes that error.

I have asynchronous pages: -

localhost:52603/Chart/Index

which doesn't error until it redirects to a page requiring a parameter like: -

localhost:52603/chart/displaymodel?modelid=5b881fc7-c789-4d24-a52f-b34a56c098e1 localhost:52603/MakeImage/DisplayMakeImage?makeId=456ab51c-a4bb-4e2a-a673-de38de4ec28d

I am using a few different technologies in the site: - EF4/ SignalR/ MEF/ Redis/ Tropo/ Log4net/ Elmah

Thanks

Comment: Are these async actions giving you trouble?

Comment: If not, could you provide more information to diagnose the problem? At least the action signature.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional information.
It looks like you may have found a bug in Glimpse. Would you mind reporting it on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues), along with the version of Glimpse and a few steps to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, I think is a bug in Glimpse 1.0.

I've just reverted to [0.87](http://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc3/0.87) and it works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

This has been confirmed as a bug in Glimpse 1.0.0.

You can [track the issue report on GitHub](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/268) to keep up to date on the progress of this bug.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Edit: This bug is now fixed and is [available in Glimpse 1.0.1](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc3)